# Concurrency control for multiple workflows under one logic app(Standard)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps, http-status-code-429

I have two workflows under one logic app (Standard). Is there anyway to stop these two workflows form running concurrently. One workflow is scheduled to run at 15 minutes intervals. And the other is running when http requests are received.

I'm experiencing 429 error when both these run at the same time. i want to stop these two from running together.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you shouldn't receive error code 429 If two workflows are running at the same time. It signifies too many requests. There might be multiples instances are running at the same time.

I have tried to invoke the workflow with **When a HTTP request is received** trigger in it at the same time when another workflow having **recurrence** trigger is executing. In my case, both completed successfully.

In order to stop the execution of multiple instances, you can enable **Concurrency Control** and set the limit as per your need. For one instance at a time, you can set the limit to 1.

[image]

Or else you can also add delays in the workflow as shown below-

[image]

In this way, you can stop running the multiple instances at the same time.